# C++/cli game wrapper error

Tags: c++cli

I am developing a game with OpenGL and C++. Right now I am in the middle of creating a c++/cli wrapper to get game data to .Net and create A a game lobby using WPF. In theory all should work without a problem but in practice not. I get a strange error :

> 1>F_Engine.lib(MuzzleFlash.h.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapViewOfFileNuma2

The F_Engine.lib is not even included in the DLL of the wrapper. Does anyone knows what is wrong with visual studio 2022?

Here is the code of the wrapper (header first and source after):

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace System;

namespace EclipseNetWrapper {
    ref class EclipseWrapper
    {
    public:
        EclipseWrapper(String^ name, String^ ip, unsigned int gameHandle, array<String^>^ players);
        void Loop();
    };
}
```

Source

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "EclipseWrapper.h"
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <Level1.h>

std::string* MarshalArray(array<String^>^ arr) {
    std::string* ret = new std::string[arr->Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr->Length; ++i) {
        String^ str = arr[i];
        std::string unManaged = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(str);
        ret[i] = unManaged;
    }

    return ret;
}

EclipseNetWrapper::EclipseWrapper::EclipseWrapper(String^ name, String^ ip, unsigned int gameHandle, array<String^>^ players)
{
    std::string n = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(name);
    std::string i = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(ip);
    Init(n, i, gameHandle, players->Length, MarshalArray(players));
}

void EclipseNetWrapper::EclipseWrapper::Loop()
{
    GameLoop();
}
```